# AngularJS Material reference field inputs

Tags: angularjs, servicenow, input-field, angularjs-material

I'm new to AngularJS Material and am trying to create a form that includes a reference field input, but can't seem to find any documentation on if this is possible.  The input I'm trying to incorporate looks like this:

[image]

When a user clicks on the magnifying glass, it would open up a pop up window that shows the different options.  I'm not so tied down to this exact look but am interested more in the functionality.  The input could be a drop down or whatever, but when clicked upon, I would like the different options to show.  I'm using ServiceNow so the reference options would be tied to a table in the back end.

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: What are you asking for? Style/html or the behavior? If is is the first one, there is a simple solution with flex row/column and little bit of extra css in case you want the button be like your picture (with borders). Otherwise, If you are looking about the behavior, you can use a [`md-menu`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu) in case of dropwdon or handle the click event and open a [`md-dialog`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a reference picker, ServiceNow offers an Angular directive for this.
The field object contains a JSON-Object with displayValue, value and name. I hope this will help you. You could find more directives provided by ServiceNow here: https://community.servicenow.com/message/1108400#1108400

```
<sn-record-picker field="FIELDOBJECT" table="'YOURTABLE'" default-query="'ENCODED QUERY'" display-field="'YOUR DISPLAYFIELD'" value-field="'VALUE'" search-fields="'SEARCHFIELD'" page-size="100"></sn-record-picker>
```